# C++ self notifying models in an MVC pattern

Tags: c++, model-view-controller

I am implementing an MVC pattern in C++. I want my model to be an Observable (or Subject) that notifies its observers automatically when changed. For some reason I don't want the client code to trigger the notification itself.

So, something like that:

```
Model model;
View view(m);
model['key1'] = 25; // (i) view is notified
model['some_vector'] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // (ii) view is notified
model['some_vector'].push_back(4); // (iii) view is notified
```

For this, my Model class will hold a map like so:

```
std::map<std::string, boost::any> m_data;
```

I scratched my head on this and I dont think the use of the assignment operator (operator=) is doable. The operator will return a reference to an any and after that no code in the model is executed, so the self-notifying nature is not possible.

I could use a function like:

```
Model::set(std::string key, boost::any value)
{
  m_data[key] = value;
  (*this).notify();
}

Model::notify() { // For loop on observers here to notify them }
```

That is well when you are creating new entry in the map but if you want to modify non integral type like in `(iii)` it does not work. Indeed I could replace the value but I can't just update it.

I thought of using a temporary object (Update) that would transfer the value to the client code and upon destruction, trigger the notification via a callback like:

```
class Update {
  Update(boost::any& value, std::function callback) : 
    m_value(value), m_callback(callback) {}
  ~Update() { m_callback(); }
  boost::any &operator() { return m_value; }
}

Model::update(std::string key) {
  return Update(m_data[key], (*this).notify());
}
```

(I am aware this does not compile, it is just to get the idea).

And then I would do something like that:

```
boost::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(model.update('some_vector')()).push_back(4);
```

And if I don't want to notify my observers for consecutive updates, I could even simulate transaction by keeping the Update object alive as long as my updates are not done:

```
{
  Update update = model.update('some_vector');
  boost::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(update()).push_back(4);
  boost::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(update()).push_back(5);
  boost::any_cast<std::vector<int>>(update()).push_back(6);
}
```

But the use of any_cast and specifying the type of the value is quite cumbersome. Anyone knows of a more concise and elegant way to acheve this ?

Comment: Use a real type to store the data instead of badly reinventing a dynamic language in C++?

Comment: Puppy, could you convert your comment to an answer?